# Open link in new window - coffescript

Tags: coffeescript

How to get beahviour similar to HTML's `target='_blank'` inside coffeescript?

so far I have tried:

```
window.location = "/site/#{pk}/goto_url/"
window.attr('target', '_blank')
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You should try

```
window.open "/site/#{pk}/goto_url/", "_blank"
```

Comment: I'm glad it helped (: If you think, this is a proper solution for your problem, please mark it as the correct answer(tick).